# Help identifying Hall sensor (95B2h)

Tags: identification

I am trying to identify a Hall-sensor located on a keyboard. There is one of these sensors underneath every key. One of them are broken and needs replacing. However, I cannot identify the component.

The markings read **95B2h**

It's a SOT-23 (or perhaps a slightly wider SOT-23W) package.

It appears to be an analog output as confirmed by oscilloscope (each sensor is connected to a Texas Instruments CD74HC4067 analog multiplexer.) The sensor is uni-polar as testing with a magnet only triggers the sensor from one direction. The supply voltage is 4V. The output voltage varies between 0-2V depending on key position.

Here is a picture of the component (this one isn't broken):
[image]

This is the pinout:
[image]

Here is a scope capture showing the supply voltage (yellow) and the output (blue) when the key is slightly depressed. My ground lead was less than optimally placed.
[image]

Comment: The supply voltage goes as low as 1.4V on some of the sensors.

Comment: Are you sure it's an analogue output - did you confirm this? Just because it goes into analogue multiplexor can't mean it's not a digital output.

Comment: Good point @Andyaka. I hooked up a scope. The signal is indeed PWM at 220Hz. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: is the supply voltage DC?

Comment: That is an even better question @jsotola. It appears the supply voltage is DC but pulsed between 0.8 and 4.0V at 80-500Hz depending on the number of keys pressed. The output is an analog voltage that I mistook for a PWM due to the varying frequency of the supply voltage. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Might you swap it for one on a key you don't use much (e.g. PrtScr) while you're looking for a replacement? If you had mentioned the manufacturer of the keyboard, maybe someone would have been able to instantly reply with a reference to the actual part. There are reddit keyboard enthusiasts who know the answer ;) Have you tried resoldering it just in case the problem is only a faulty solder joint?

Comment: Hello @AndrewMorton. This is a good idea. It's one of those smaller keyboards though. Not a single superfluous key. But that tilde sign next to the backspace is perhaps a worthy sacrifice. I'm still hoping the manufacturer decides to replace the whole thing since its a brand new keyboard. I'm holding off on the name until they've decide what to do. Don't want to agitate anyone needlessly. Give that its an analog keyboard, with few keys, I bet any sufficiently enthusiastic Redditor can figure out which keyboard it is. I don't use Reddit, but would it be a better forums for this?

Comment: @wronex You need information, and if reddit can give you that information then it would seem reasonable to ask there... Oh, and remember to use flux when soldering. Flux is cheap, and failure to use flux can be very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

If your measurements are correct, it means that Wooting might be using custom analog-output, hall-effect sensors. Out of the many analog-output, hall-effect sensors I’ve looked at, only one has been unipolar, and none output 0V.

Comment: The DRV5056 has a device marking of [**56A1Z**](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv5056-q1.pdf#page=21), while the IC in question has a marking of **95B2h**.